# How to make an SQL query where in WHERE there will be 2 times "AND"

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Please help me deal with a seemingly simple sql query, but which does not work, I have already tried all the options through JOIN and through variations in WHERE

Таблица User

| id | status | postId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | new | 55555 |
| 23456 | ready | 55555 |
| 34567 | done | 77777 |

I need to output postId if it has status = new **And** status = ready.
postId = 55555 should be output
My option:

```
SELECT
       postId
FROM User
WHERE postId IN (55555, 77777)
AND (status = new AND status = ready)
GROUP BY postId
```

But it does not work because of a contradiction (status = new AND status = ready), it only works (status = new OR status = ready), but such a condition does not suit me, it needs to be strictly both new and ready.
MySql.

I also have SQL with nested request:

```
SELECT postId FROM User WHERE status = ready AND postId IN 
    (SELECT postId FROM User WHERE status = new )
```

It works, but if I need process more than 2 status the request becomes more complicated

Answer (score 1):

To make your first approach work, you need to assert the status requirements in the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT postId
FROM User
WHERE postId IN (55555, 77777)
GROUP BY postId
HAVING SUM(status = 'new') > 0 AND SUM(status = 'ready') > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.POSTID
FROM USER AS U
WHERE U.STATUS='NEW' 
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM USER AS U2 WHERE U.POSTID=U2.POSTID AND U2.STATUS='READY'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to output postId if it has status = new And status = ready

An easy solution:

```
select postId
from User
where status in ('new','ready')
group by postId
having count(distinct status) =2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da123e47eef3998f4d984453ca96b790

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation with distinct:

```
select postId
from T
where postId in (55555,77777)
  and status in ('new','ready')
group by postId
having Count(distinct status) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
SELECT
       postId
FROM User u
WHERE postId IN (55555, 77777)
AND status = new AND EXISTS(
    select postId 
    from User u2 
    WHERE postId IN (55555, 77777) 
    and status = ready 
    and u2.postID = u.postId)
```